# Is space of measures Inner product space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{F})$ be measurable space and let $\mathcal{M}$ be space of all signed measures on it. It is clear that, $\mathcal{M}$ is a Real vector space. I am interested to know if there is any non-trivial inner product on this space and can we make it as Hilbert space. Thanks

Comment: How is it a real vector space? What is $-1$ times a measure?

Comment: I will define it set-wise i.e. $2\mu$ for any set $A$ would be $2*\mu(A)$. This is similar to how we do it for real valued functions on a given set.

Comment: Measures are nonnegative-valued, however...

Comment: I am considering signed measures here

Comment: Are you looking at signed Borel measures, or all of them?

Comment: All of them! But does considering only signed Borel measures help?

Comment: If you consider only Borel measures, then the answer is No, because its pre-dual is $C_0(X)$, which is not a Hilbert space (whereas the pre-dual of Hilbert space must be isomorphic to itself)

Comment: Thanks. But what if there is no topology on $X$?

Comment: Does $\mathcal{M}$ have any predefined norm or it is just real vector space

Comment: One of the possible norms is "sup" norm or uniform norm. However, it doesn't come from inner product. So, we need to define a norm such that it comes from an inner product.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter what $\mathcal{M}$ actually is. You can formulate your question just for arbitrary linear space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not put any additional structure on $\mathcal{M}$ except the real vector space structure, it doesn't matter that we are talking about space of measures. We just need to know that we have some real vector space $V$.

Let $\kappa$ be the cardinality of Hamel basis of $V$. Assume we *have* a Hilbert space $H$ whose algebraic dimension is $\kappa$, then we have a linear bijection $T:V\to H$. Now to make $V$ a Hilbert space it is enough to put $\Vert v\Vert=\Vert T(v)\Vert_H$.

The only problem is to check whether we do have at least one Hilbert space with algebraic dimension $\kappa$ for a given cardinal  $\kappa$. In [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-009-3190-6) article under so called hypothesis $(H)$ it is proved that $\dim\; \ell_2(\kappa)=\kappa$, but it is unknow whether this hypothesis can be proved in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Thanks to [Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/49437/martin), who pointed out this problem in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427834/can-all-real-complex-vector-spaces-be-equipped-with-a-hilbert-space-structure?lq=1#comment915081_427947) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427834/can-all-real-complex-vector-spaces-be-equipped-with-a-hilbert-space-structure?lq=1#comment915084_427947) comment.