# finding the algebraic dimension of $\ell^p$ spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

I want to know "how we can find the algebraic dimension(the cardinal number of the Hamel basis) for $\ell^p$ spaces." What can we say about $\ell^p(I)$, where $I$ is an infinite set?\

Moreover, for any given cardinal number $\alpha \neq \aleph_0$, is there a Banach space $X$ that its algebraic dimension equal $\alpha$?

Comment: see comments by to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427834/can-all-real-complex-vector-spaces-be-equipped-with-a-hilbert-space-structure)

Comment: I think no identity meant [this answer by Andres Caicedo](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/427947/). (The link did not point directly to it.)

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis-of-ell-1-mathbbr